# SharePoint SE timer job job-webconfig-modification exists

Tags: timer-jobs

I am trying to confirm in SharePoint SE whether the timer job for modifying webconfigs is still available. In other earlier versions it is called job-webconfig-modifications. I have tried searching for it, but can't find it. Is it used or is called by a different name, and if so what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same; you will see it when you change the web.config file using the SharePoint Powershell.

You can run the following code to get the running jobs

Get-SPTimerJob -Identity "job-webconfig-modification" | Format-Table DisplayName,Id,LastRunTime,Status

some sample code to update the web.config

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://test:8000/
$mod = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$mod.Path = “configuration/SharePoint/WebPartLimits”
$mod.Name = “MaxZoneParts”
$mod.Value = “100”
$mod.Sequence = 0
$mod.Owner = “webpartmod”
$mod.Type = 1    
$app.WebConfigModifications.Add($mod)
$app.update()
$app.WebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```